# What is the difference between .gch and .pch precompiled headers?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, precompiled-headers

By default gcc generates .gch precompiled headers. However clang expects .pch headers. When running scan-build with clang on an otherwise gcc based project, I get errors due to this. What are the differences between the two file formats that might cause this problem?

Comment: It is not like you can mix compilers anyway.

Comment: No, but I want to build a compile database for cquery for a project that uses gcc to compile, and hence gch headers. Hence my question. I am NOT trying to mix compilers. As I said above I just want to run scan-build on the project.

Answer (score 6):

The primary difference is that headers pre-compiled by clang are only compatible with clang, and headers pre-compiled by GCC are only compatible with GCC. This is a difference that is likely to cause your problem.

Furthermore, pre-compiled headers are only compatible with particular version of compiler, as well as particular set of compilation options. If any of the mentioned aspects change, those headers must be re-compiled.

Comment: As for solving the problem, I'm not sure, but I would try to simply first delete all gch files before running scan-build.